# React-bootstrap Nabar.Offcanvas causing errors with Jest/testing-library tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-bootstrap, react-testing-library, testing-library

I am working with a navbar.offcanvas element for responsive navigation menus. I just ran my tests, which pass when I comment out the navbar.offcanvas element. I am using React-Bootstrap, Jest, and testing-library/react.

When I leave the element in and run tests, I get the following:

```
    TypeError: targetWindow.matchMedia is not a function

      56 | test("Try to render element", () => {
      57 |   // Arrange
    > 58 |   render(<TodoList />);
         |   ^
```

I am not sure why this occurs.

Here is the Navbar.Offcanvas

```
<Navbar.Offcanvas
            id={`offcanvasNavbar-expand-md`}
            aria-labelledby={`offcanvasNavbarLabel-expand-md`}
            placement="start"
          >
            <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
              <Offcanvas.Title id={`offcanvasNavbarLabel-expand-md`}>
                Navigation
              </Offcanvas.Title>
            </Offcanvas.Header>
            <Offcanvas.Body>
              <Nav>
                {pages.map((page) => {
                  return (
                    <Nav.Item key={page.path}>
                      <Nav.Link
                        href={page.path}
                        eventKey={page.path}
                        onSelect={(k) => setKey(k)}
                        className="layout-nav-link"
                      >
                        {page.name}
                      </Nav.Link>
                    </Nav.Item>
                  );
                })}
              </Nav>
            </Offcanvas.Body>
          </Navbar.Offcanvas>
```

Here are the tests

```
test("Renders TodoList", () => {
  render(<TodoList />);
  const todoList = screen.getByText("Todo List");
  expect(todoList).toHaveTextContent("Todo List");
});

test("Type into TodoList input box", () => {
  // Arrange
  render(<TodoList />);
  const todoListInput = screen.getByLabelText("TodoId");
  console.log(todoListInput);

  // Act
  fireEvent.change(todoListInput, {
    target: { value: "Run" },
  });

  // Assert
  expect(todoListInput.value).toBe("Run");

  // Act
  fireEvent.change(todoListInput, {
    target: { value: "" },
  });

  // Assert
  expect(todoListInput.value).toBe("");
});
```

If you need any additional information, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: I am still new to using Jest so this may not be the recommended way of fixing the issue. This is the only workaround I could come up with considering my limited knowledge.

I ended up adding the following to my arrange sections in each test that was causing issues:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
  })),
});
```

So it will look like:

```js
test("Renders TodoList", () => {

Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
  })),
});

  render(<TodoList />);
  const todoList = screen.getByText("Todo List");
  expect(todoList).toHaveTextContent("Todo List");
});
```

Essentially, I had a method from React Bootstrap that uses matchMedia somewhere but since JSDOM does not implement it (Jest uses JSDOM) I need to mock it. Now my tests are happy... for now. Hope this helps.

Reference: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom